# Simulating data for logistic regression with unbalanced classes

Tags: r, logistic, simulation

I want to simulate categorical data for logistic regression, and those data need to have unbalanced class representation.  Simulating for logistic regression with (nearly) balanced classes is simple enough in R:

```
n <- 500
x <- rnorm(n)
lp <- x * log(1.5) # log of the odds ratio - coefficient of the linear predictor
pr <- 1 / (1 + exp(-lp))
y <- rbinom(n,1,pr)
```

If I run this 10,000 times and look at the mean of the exponentiated coefficient, it always comes out nearly 1.5.

But what if I want the same odds ratio and have a sampling that provides 25% cases and 75% controls?  The only approach I've come up with is to simulate too many examples, and then down-sample the appropriate amounts from each class:

```
  n <- 500
  perc.case <- 0.25
  x <- rnorm(n*1/perc.case) # simulate more than we need by a factor consistent with the imbalance
  lp <- x * log(1.5)
  pr <- 1 / (1 + exp(-lp))
  y  <- rbinom(n*1/perc.case,1,pr) # again, simulate more than necessary
  
  n.case = n*perc.case
  n.control = n*(1-perc.case)
  y.case <- sample(which(y==1), n.case, replace = FALSE)
  y.control <- sample(which(y==0), n.control, replace = FALSE)
  
  x <- x[c(y.case,y.control)]
  y <- y[c(y.case,y.control)]
```

My interpretation is that I'm simulating a population and then sampling from that population.  I tend to get a similar degree of error in the coefficient estimate as with the balanced case, but I want to make sure I'm not misinterpreting something or introducing an additional bias.

Comment: Do you care about the distribution of values in your case, or do you just want any reasonable-looking imbalanced dataset?

Comment: Good point.  At this stage, I'm not worried about the distribution within a class as long as I can maintain the odds ratio between classes.  That being said, if you have a method to target a specific within class distribution, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: If you don't care about the distribution at all, you can just modify `pr` before plugging it into the `y` computation...

Comment: If you do care about the distribution, I'd just take $x$ from a Gaussian mixture model (or even more simply - I'd plug in a probability $p_1$ to subtract or add some quantity $q_1$ from $x$.

Comment: If I modify pr, won't that affect the odds ratio?  I need to guarantee that the odds ratio is maintained.